# Discord.py not excecuting

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, replit

This is my code in python whenever I click the start button it automatically stops by the way I am using replit IDE.

```
import discord



class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged on as {self.user}!')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print(f'Message from {message.author}: {message.content}')

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = MyClient(intents=intents)


class MyClient(discord.Client):

  async def on_ready(self):
    print(f'Logged on as {self.user}!')

  async def on_message(self, message):
    print(f'Message from {message.author}: {message.content}')


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = MyClient(intents=intents)
import asyncio
async def client_start():
    await client.start('XYZ')
```

I really don't know what to try I expected the application to be started automatically, I am not a python expert my friend asked me this, now I am asking you guys kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start a server, otherwise, it won't keep running.

Try this:
https://github.com/sdrrv/Fate-Wielding-Bot/blob/master/keep_alive.py

Comment: Important to note that I don't think replit allows bot hosting any longer... Pretty sure they fix that. Back in the day, you could trick the system by having https://uptimerobot.com/ ping the server, and replit would host the bot for you.

Comment: I now host my bot in a rasberrypi I bought. Pretty cool project :)

Answer (score 0):

You're never starting it. You created a `client_start()` function, but you're not using it so all this script does is create some variables & then exit.

Next, your code seems to have the same things twice, barring different indentation levels. That doesn't seem right. Is this a mistake in your post or does it actually look like that?

Also, stop abusing replit to run bots on. It's not what the platform was designed for, and it brings loads of issues along with it that you can't do anything about (like getting ratelimited because of other people). Get an actual VPS or host it yourself.

Comment: I don't know about this at all, this is my friend's bot I probably mentioned that I don't work with python well I ll send him this thanks!